# What is the difference between appending to an empty list and reassigning it?

Tags: python, list, append

If we create an empty list then we can fill this list by either appending "something"

```
list_ex1 = []
list_ex1.append(1)
print(list_ex1)
[1]
```

or we can reassign an empty list as the same "something".

```
list_ex2 = []
list_ex2 = [1]
print(list_ex2)
[1]
```

Great, we get the same result. However, there must be some very different happenings going on in the background. This became obvious when I was using tkinter to create a simple UI with some buttons on it.

```
def Multi_Import_Match(imp):
    imp_fill = []
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Select Name')
    win.geometry("500x100")
    b = []

    def but_call(imp):
        imp_fill.append(imp) # Here is where the problem became apparent!!
        win.destroy()

    for i in range(0,len(imp)):
        b.append(Button(win, text=imp[i], command=lambda i=i: but_call(imp[i])))
        b[i].pack()
    mainloop()
    return imp_fill
```

I struggled for a while to get the expected output from my UI when using `imp_fill = imp` but it only returned an empty list. With `imp_fill.append(imp)` the code worked perfectly and returned my desired string. **Why is it that the append works and the reassignment does not?**

NB: the variable imp was a small list of strings.

Comment: Were you having trouble using `imp_fill = imp` or `imp_fill = [imp]`? The difference makes them two different data types.

Comment: Both, I get only an empty list `[]` where as I "should" get a string or a list with a single string entry respectively. I get a list with a single string entry with my working `imp_fill.append(imp)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is scope. Python will search outer levels of scope if it can't find a local definition for a name. That's why this can work:

```
val = "hello"
def print_val():
    print(val)
print_val()
# hello
```

This becomes more confusing with lists though, as they're mutable. That means that if you append to a list from within a function, you *are* affecting it in the original scope. See this:

```
val = []
def print_val():
    val.append("hello")
    print(val)

print(val)
# []
print_val()
# ['hello']
print(val)
# ['hello']
```

The list is originally empty, but after calling `print_val` the list is appended to. This affects the actual list, which in turn means that when you just print it normally it has `'hello'` in it.

In your case, if you just did the equivalent of `val = ['hello']` inside the function, that only affects the value of `val` *within* the function, and nothing happens to the original scoped name. The solution is to either use `return [val]` to get the value from the function's scope or to use `append` as you did, which modifies the actual value that exists outside the function.

Comment: So just to clarify, appending a list within a function changes it globally? Where as reassigning only changes the variable within the function and keeps it intact outside of the function?

Comment: @josh Exactly. When you re-assign it you're actually creating an entirely new separate list, `append` just modifies the original.

Answer (score 2):

The difference comes from the fact that a list is a mutable object. So other references to same object are changed accordingly when you *modify* the object, but are left alone when you affect the reference to a different object

Let's use your example with an alternate reference:

```
>>> list_ex1 = []
>>> old = list_ex1
>>> list_ex1.append(1)
>>> print(list_ex1)
[1]
>>> old
[1]
>>> old is list_ex1
True

>>> list_ex2 = []
>>> old2 = list_ex2
>>> list_ex2 = [1]
>>> print(list_ex2)
[1]
>>> old2
[]
>>> old2 is list_ex2
False
```

In your example *modifying* the list with `append` also modifies the original object, where as *affecting* it only changes a local copy and leave the original object untouched.

Comment: This is very interesting. I did not know that there would remain a link between the two variables old2 and list_ex2 post-assignment (`old2 = list_ex2`).

Answer (score 0):

First off, from a reading of this code, you should really change the argument name for the `but_call()` function to avoid confusion. The argument seems to be an element of the `list` `imp`, not your variable `imp` itself. Clarity is the key here.

Secondly, you are right that the statements are different:

`imp_fill = imp` replaces the pre-existing value of `fill_imp` (`[]` at start but changes every time this statement is executed) with that of `imp` (whatever it may be - `list`, `str`, `int`, `object`, ...)

`imp_fill = [imp]` replaces the pre-existing value of `fill_imp` with a `list` which has one element - the value of `imp`

`imp_fill.append(imp)` takes the pre-existing `list` and expands it by 1 element, which is the value of `imp`

So:

```
>>> a = [2]
>>> a = [9, 5]
>>> print(a)
[9, 5]

>>> a = [2]
>>> a = 943
>>> print(a)
943

>>> a = [2]
>>> a.append(98)
>>> print(a)
[2, 98]
```